# Whats the common name for DSL where the Upload speed is higher?

Tags: dsl

Wikipedia defines ADSL like this:

> In ADSL, the data throughput in the upstream direction (the direction to the service provider) is lower, hence the designation of asymmetric service

But how is it called when the upstream is *higher*?

Sorry for the short question, thats about it, i couldnt find anything about this online because, as you can imagine, googling "ADSL with higher upload speed" does not give the desired results.

Comment: If you want higher upload speed, you will have to pay for it.  Generally, ISPs sell either oversubscribed connections (asymmetric or symmetric), or guaranteed connections (usually symmetric) for businesses.  Oversubscribed meaning they have 1000 Mbps available to the neighborhood, and sell "up to 100 Mbps" connections to a hundred houses.  Since not everyone downloads all the time, it's usually not a problem.  For a business which actually requires the full bandwidth all of the time, the ISP sells an unshared connection.  It's possible to have higher upload, but I've never seen it advertised.

Comment: Uhm, thanks, but i know that and dont quite get what this has to do with my question?

Comment: "I have never seen it advertised" is a softer way of saying "It doesn't exist".  You can get a more certain answer by asking the same question of ISPs, who are glad to sell their services to you.  If you find out, feel free to put an Answer below with your findings.

Answer (score 1):

"Asymmetric" doesn't make the distinction between which side is higher, just that the connection does not have the same speed in both directions. If it were so configured with appropriate networking gear then it could easily be the other way around.

It is just convention that for "home" users that the priority is for data headed to the homes. The telco could *in theory* swap the bandwidth priorities and thus make the connection primarily an upload service. In practice though you'd likely find it difficult to get through to anyone at a conventional telco that would know what you are talking about, let alone anyone that could make it happen.

Comment: Ah, yea, i thought so, i was just irritated because wikipedia defined it so directly - by the way, my company does have higher upload speed, im guessing because we host services that are used at other locations inside our company (speedtest gives 20down / 30up)

Answer (score 0):

The "A" in ADSL stands for "Asymmetric" as to indicate the difference in upload and download speed. What you are looking for is the plain opposite; the Symmetric Digital Subscriber Line, or [SDSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_digital_subscriber_line) family of technologies.

Technologies allowing upload speeds that are strictly higher than the downward stream, when both are at their maximum, do not yet exist, as far as I know.

Note that while optical fibre allows equal upload and download speeds, it does not count as SDSL as the technology is entirely different.